# Finding if single integer is in an array of integers

Tags: c#, xamarin

First time posting on stackoverflow! I'm making a map for a text adventure in c# and am wondering if there is an easy way to find out if an int is in an array of ints with an if statement.

psuedo of what i'm trying to do:

```
int[] NorthCliff = {15,14,13,12};
int Currentroom 15;  
if(currentroom is in NorthCliff)
{
  //do things 
}
```

Pardon my newness, this is for an app on xamarin. None of the other example from this site could help me either.

Comment: FYI, this is basic C#/.NET, there is nothing Xamarin specific about it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this code

```
int[] NorthCliff = {15,14,13,12};
int Currentroom = 15;  
if(NorthCliff.Contains(Currentroom))
{
//do things 
}
```

Remember to add "using System.Linq"

Comment: do you really need Linq for that?

Comment: Yes, "Contains" is an extension method found in the System.Linq namespace.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Array.IndexOf(NorthCliff, Currentroom)
```

to get the index of a value or `-1` if it doesn't exist. So, if the return value from that is zero or greater, it was found in the array.

The following program shows this in action:

```
using System;
namespace ConsoleApplication1 {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            int[] NorthCliff = {15,14,13,12};
            for (int i = 12; i < 17; i++) {
                Console.WriteLine(Array.IndexOf(NorthCliff, i));
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

and outputs:

```
3
2
1
0
-1
```